# applying a bit vector for mask

Tags: c++, bitmask, uint64

I want to do a simple bit mask operation. Lets say

```
uint64_t a = 348659235483;
```

Assuming this number is converted to binary, I want to extract the values from bit 6 to 12 (0 is MSB on the right end). What is the smallest code for that?

the binary is

```
10100010010110110110101101/110101/0011011
```

So I want to save `110101` which is `53`

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with them.

Comment: I want to save the number from position 6 to 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
uint64_t a = 348659235483;
uint64_t result = (a & 0x0fe0) >> 6;
```